# List_unsubscribe - YiiMailer (extends PHPMailer)

Tags: email, yii, gmail, email-headers, unsubscribe

Can't set List-Unsubscribe in a right way - can't see Unsubscribe in sent gmail mails.

Tried next varriants:

1. `$mail->setAddresses('List-Unsubscribe', $unsubscribeUrl);`
2. `$mail->AddCustomHeader('List-Unsubscribe: <'.$unsubscribeUrl.'>');`
3. `$mail->setAddresses('List-Unsubscribe', <'.$unsubscribeUrl.'>');`

`$unsubscribeUrl` - it is URL to unsubscribe member.
Sobody said to me that I should use mailto, but I do not know how to handle this mailto.

How can I set List-Unsubscribe header?